# How to place the label above the input text in a Material UI TextField component when there's a Start Adornment?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Just as the title says, I've been trying to get this done, but for the life of me I don't know which Material UI css class manipulate to get this done. I have tried playing around with the InputLabelProps (shrink class to be exact), but it just didn't work. I have a reusable TextField component created:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    textFieldInput: {
        fontFamily: globalFonts.montserrat,
        fontSize: 13,
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    textFieldRoot: {
        borderRadius: 8,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: "1px solid #F5F5F5",
    }
});

export default function TextInput({error, label, onChange, value, InputLabelProps, InputProps, inputProps, icon, disabled, type, helperText}: Props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <TextField
            type={type}
            fullWidth
            label={label}
            value={value}
            variant='filled'
            onChange={(e) => {onChange(e)}}
            inputProps={inputProps}
            InputProps={
                InputProps ? InputProps :
                {
                    classes: {input: classes.textFieldInput, root: classes.textFieldRoot},
                    startAdornment: icon ? <InputAdornment position='start'>{icon}</InputAdornment> : undefined,
                    disableUnderline: true,                    
                }
            }
            InputLabelProps={InputLabelProps}
            error={error ? error(value) : false}
            helperText={helperText}
            disabled={disabled}
        />
    )
}
```

[image: This is how it looks currently]

[image: This is how it should look]

Does anyone have idea how to place the label above the inputted text, or have any of you met this problem before?

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cdn-c6p3xc

Answer (score 1):

adding a marginLeft to the label should do the trick

```
label: {
    "&.MuiInputLabel-filled.MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
      color: "#000000",
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Medium",
      marginLeft: "35px"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, but as this is a reusable component, an absolute margin is not enough, because the icon sizes might differ a bit, thus the label and text would still not be aligned.